# Изменения размеров изображения на разных устройствах

Tags: изображения, resize

Требуется отобразить узкое изображение на мобильном устройстве — изменить размер пропорционально.

Применяю такой *jquery*-скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var heightR = $(window).height();// высота экрана
  var widthR = $(window).width();// ширина экрана
  $('#bg').css({'width':widthR,'height':heightR}); 
});
```

css:

```
#bg{
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;}
```

И все отрабатывает на отлично, как надо. Но при смене ориентации устройства новые свойства ширины и высоты не задаются — нужно обновлять страницу. Т.е. высота и ширина задаются только в момент загрузки страницы.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно отлавливать событие `resize` для окна. Некоторые браузеры/устройства поддерживают событие `orientationchange`.

```
// Прослушивание смены ориентации
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    // изменение размеров картинки
}, false);
```

Или (более надёжно/распространённо)

```
// событие: изменение размера окна
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    // изменение размера картинки
}, false);
```

Существуют так же медиа-запросы (Media Queries) CSS вот пример:

```
/* портрет */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* стили для портретной картинки */
}
/* альбом */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* стили для альбомной картинки */
}
```

[источник](http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change) (*англ.*)
[первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996839/1816872) (*англ.*)

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [orientationchange](/questions/tagged/orientationchange)

Answer (score 0):

Используй `css-media`. Можно по ориентации, можно по точным размерам подгонять `css`.

```
min-height
max-height

min-width
max-width
```